# Changing user in Connection String of web.config

Tags: c#, sql

Simple webpage backed by C# where the web.config has a connection string to sql server. We're trying to migrate that server, and this page to look to the new one. Whenever I modify the web.config, it produces a Server Error on the page. 
First I tried changing the Data Source Name to look at the new server. Then I just tried changing the User ID/password to our SA account. Both resulted in server error.

```
<add name="Directory" connectionString="Data Source=SERVERA; Database=Directory; User ID=phone_user; Password=XXXXX"/>
```

Stack Trace fails at `SubSonic.SqlQuery.ExecuteReader()`

> Sql Query Exception: Format of the initialization string does not
>   conform to specification starting at index 0.

Is there any additional information I need to provide?

Comment: Is your sample connection string the old or new one? What database are you using (MS SQL Server)?

Comment: Sample connection string would be old. Basically trying to change Data Source from ServerA to ServerB. Yes, MS SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your connection string to one of the following:

```
Server=SERVERB;Database=Directory;User Id=phone_user;Password=XXXXXX;
```

or

```
Data Source=SERVERB;Initial Catalog=Directory;User Id=phone_user;Password=XXXXXX;
```

I am not sure `Data Source` and `Database` combination is 100% valid whereas the above two examples should work.

A great source information about connection strings (MS SQL Server) here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ and it has many others!

**EDIT**

In addition check you are getting / using connection string correctly, a simple example:

```
string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Directory"].ConnectionString;
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Both of those combinations also resulted in the same server error. I will check out the link

Comment: I have added an edit to ensure that you are getting / using connection string correctly.